# Strugling with receiving data to RPi from BT-connected device

Tags: raspbian-buster

I am struggling with how to receive data on a RPi 3 (Model B Plus Rev 1.3) from a bluetooth connected 'sender' device (a BT-enabled scale).

When I pair and connect the 'sender' device by bluetooth I get the message 'serial interface on WT11i-A is now available through /dev/rfcomm1'

And indeed the 'sender' device seems to be connected ok:
[image]

The RPi also seems to be sending/receiving data somehow:
[image]

When I press the button on the sender device which sends data the 'B/s' values next to the data activity icons in the right bottom corner go up to values like 200-500 B/s.

Under local services it is indicated that the data is supposed to land in downloads:
[image]
and under 'Receiving Files (Object Push)' the 'Accept files from trusted devices' option is checked.

RFCOMM shows:
[image]

I have also tried running the following Python code:

```
import bluetooth

#00:07:80:E0:A4:FC
host = ""
port = 1105
server = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
print('Bluetooth Socket Created')

try:
   server.bind((host, port))
   print("Bluetooth Binding Completed")
except:
   print("Bluetooth Binding Failed")

server.listen(1105)

try:
    client, address = server.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", address)
    print("Client: ", client)
except Exception as e:
    print (str(e))

try:
   while True:
      data = client.recv(1)
      print(data)
      client.send(data)
except:
   client.close()
   server.close()
```

The code hangs and after ctrl-c I get the following message:
[image]
I have googled: "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 167, in accept
client, addr = self._sock.accept ()
but find nothing that I am able to comprehend.

Also: on my Android phone I am using the Serial Bluetooth app ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/deta ... e_CH&gl=US ) and it works fine, meaning the sender device is sending the data to the phone as required.

I see however no data in 'downloads' nor under 'tmp' and I am quite lost at this point

Suggestions/assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a long journey the conclusion is: dont connect using RFCOMM. Instead I got the solution working very easily with bluedot ( https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothclient ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).